# I want to set tick in tableview cell for row at indexpath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4, xcode10

i am adding multiple selection in tableview with sections in tableview, so how can i store that section index as well as indexpath of that cell for display when user click on cell inside that particular sections that will store in array as selected item and reflect in cellForRowAtindexpath the better solution is appreciated

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemsInSections[section].count
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.sections.count;
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 8/255, green: 38/255, blue: 76/255, alpha: 1.0)
    header.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tablheaders.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    let section = indexPath.section
    if checkdarray.count > 0
    {
        if (self.checkdarray[section][indexPath.row] as Int == 1)
        {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType = .none;
        }
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = itemsInSections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] as! String

    return cell

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     let section = indexPath.section as Int
    let indepaths = indexPath.row as Int
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    checkdarray.insert([1], at: [section][indepaths])
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
   // checkdarray.remove(at: indexPath.row)

    //checkdarray.insert(0, at: indexPath.row)
}
```

Comment: I would use a `Set<IndexPath>` and then just insert/remove the index path as required.  You then use `contains` in `cellForRow(at:)`

Comment: you mean just using indexpath for selected item store in array and get in cellForRow(at:) compare that array item with indexpath.row @Dávid Pásztor

Comment: Don't store it in an array, store it in a `Set`

Comment: do you have any example for quick understand ? @Paulw11

Comment: @Paulw11 Why Set is preferred over Array?

Comment: `var selected = Set<IndexPath>()`. `selected.insert(indexPath)`.  A set is preferred because you can efficiently determine if the set contains an item and you don't need to worry about indicies

Comment: @all who are suggesting an index path set: **Don’t use separate collections to save data which actually belongs to the model**. That’s very bad practice. At the latest if cells can be moved you are in trouble. Add the `isSelected` information to the data model. When the selection changes update the model and reload the row.

Comment: Short example would be great to understand your model update @vadian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient and reliable solution is to keep the `isSelected` state in the data model.

Use a struct as data model and add a member `isSelected` along with the other information you need.

```
struct Model {
    var isSelected = false
    var someOtherMember : String

    // other declarations
}
```

In `cellForRow` set the checkmark according to the `isSelected` member

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) // use always the passed tableView instance

    let model = itemsInSections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.accessoryType = model.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
    cell.textLabel?.text = model.someOtherMember

    return cell

}
```

In `didSelectRowAt` and `didDeselectRowAt` update the model and reload the row

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    itemsInSections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].isSelected = true
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    itemsInSections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].isSelected = false
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

**Never** use an extra array to save index paths. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have used button in table...
// declare var
 var checkarrMenu = Set<IndexPath>()

// In tableView
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = mManageTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCellID")as! TableViewCell
        cell.mRadioBtnAct.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.mRadioBtnAct.addTarget(self, action: #selector(mRadioCheck(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        if checkarrMenu.contains(indexPath){
            cell.mradioimage.image = UIImage(named: "Radiochecked")
        }else{
            cell.mradioimage.image = UIImage(named: "Radio checkedlightRadio3")
        }
        return cell
    }
// on radio btn Action
 @objc func mRadioCheck(sender:UIButton){
        let touchPoint: CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: mManageTableView)
        // maintable --> replace your tableview name
        let clickedButtonIndexPath = mManageTableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint)
        if checkarrMenu.contains(clickedButtonIndexPath){
            checkarrMenu.remove(clickedButtonIndexPath)

        }else{
            checkarrMenu.insert(clickedButtonIndexPath)

            }
        tableView.reloadData()
       }
// hope its works for you!
```

Comment: Don't use `NSMutableArray` in Swift unless necessary for Objective C interoperability

Comment: okk then i will use set of indexPath Set<IndexPath>() , answer updated

Comment: @Paulw11 so what we can use instead of this NSMutableArray, it seems like he is storing button position which is pretty like indexpath row, i tried his code and i get result like below output of that array ->  (                      "<NSIndexPath: 0x600000688c80> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}"),
    ( "<NSIndexPath: 0x600000689c40> {length = 2, path = 1 - 0}")